# Chrome dictionary extensions: Right Click > Look Up in Google Definitions?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, dictionary

Does anyone know of an easy Chrome extension whose functionality includes the ability to right-click a word and select some "Define" option from the right-click menu, that will then open up a new tab for a Google `Define: term` query?

Answer (score 5):

The [Define extension](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/dkfohljnogkakijpbgoebdcbgllabgbm?hl=en) should do you the trick.

Once you install it you get the option of looking up the definition in either Google, Merriam-Webster or Dictionary.com and will open in a background tab.

You can select which language to default on if you open up definitions via Google Dictionary.

If you want even simpler, install [Google Dictionary](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mgijmajocgfcbeboacabfgobmjgjcoja). You only need to double-click on a word and it will bring up a pop-up with the definition. Said pop-up will include a link to the Google Dictionary page of the selected word.

Comment: Thank you! Loads better for me than, say, the stock Google dictionary extension.

Nit-picking is home nowhere if not the Internet, so I must insist: is there a similar extension that doesn't require two clicks to pull up the definition page? 

(Maybe I should just learn to live with it rather than detailing these incredibly minute gripes...)

Comment: Haven't found another extension yet that is few clicks to bring up the definition. Maybe someone else will @moo

Comment: even quicker.. The google dictionary extension https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-dictionary-by-goog/mgijmajocgfcbeboacabfgobmjgjcoja    you can select a word hit CTRL or another key and a popup shows the definition. The option is in extension options if you click the button at the top that the extension produces http://i.imgur.com/ehAOUxS.png   you then click extension options (or from tools..extensions..the options for google dictionary), then see  a section called "pop-up definition" in the options, and choose ctrl when you select it. And it does it for double click too.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Context Menu Search](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ocpcmghnefmdhljkoiapafejjohldoga). With it, I've set up links to not just a dictionary and thesaurus but a quick way to find a route from home to a selected address, searches in Amazon, IMDB, YouTube and so on.